# Limit Mongo.db access to a structure to 1 user at a time

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a Gallery collection which has an `images` array

```
[
{
  _id: "549e2a2bdb9021b51d96ac84",
  images: [
  {
    path: "abc123.png",
    recycles: 0
  }
  ]
},
{
  _id: "549e2a2bdb9021b51d96ac85",
  images: [
{
  path: "abc123.png",
  recycles: 0
}
]
}
]
```

Alice requests a Gallery with only 1 image.
Alice will upload a second image to this Gallery.
Bob requests a Gallery with only 1 image. How do I mark the first Gallery so that Bob doesn't get the same image from Alice?

I'm considering marking the first Gallery with an accessed timestamp when Alice requests it.

If Alice doesn't upload a second image to the Gallery within N minutes, and Bob requests a new Gallery, then he'll get the first one.

My question is what is a good JSON structure for this design & what is an efficient way to construct the Mongo query?

I'm open to alternative designs to give a user 1 Gallery that only has 1 Image in it at a time.

ELABORATIONS:

Gallery == battle.

I'm building an "image battle" application. The end client will download a "battle" which has  1 or 2 images. In either case, the user picks 1 of the existing images, takes their own image then uploads.

So I don't want Bob, Carly and David to all upload an image to Alice's Battle -- it's supposed to be just 2 images. Once Bob uploads an image to Alice's battle -- then Carly could download the battle, pick which one she likes, upload her own, then David (or anyone) could download it.. repeat.

Comment: Please elaborate your use case a bit – it is a bit abstract. Why does Bob need to access the gallery with only one pic _after_ Alice uploaded a second one?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg added elaboration thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the use case, but tracking "occupied" galleries using a timestamp for the start of the occupation seems reasonable. You can use queries on the timestamp to find unoccupied galleries by checking if the occupied timestamp is older than N minutes, defaulting the timestamp to some time longer than N minutes back from when the application first started.